# How do I convert 01 January 2002 into a VB.NET Date Format

Tags: vb.net, date, time, format

How do I convert 01 January 2002 into a VB.NET Date Format

I work out the days from that date until today in VB.net

Thanks

Comment: [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.Parse` is used to Parse a string to a date.

Then take this away from `DateTime.Now` to find the number of days:

```
MessageBox.Show((DateTime.Now - Date.Parse("01 January 2002")).TotalDays.ToString())
```

No need for `DateTime.ParseExact` here because that date cannot be ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting arbitrary text, say from an end user, you should use TryParse instead. The Parse method will throw an exception if the parsing fails. TryParse does not. Instead, it will set a variable and return True if the parse was successful. If the string could not be parsed, the variable is untouched and False is returned.

```
Dim TempDate As Date
If Date.TryParse("some string", TempDate) Then
    'Work with the TempDate, it was set correctly.
    MessageBox.Show(TempDate.ToString)
Else
    'The string could not be parsed
    MessageBox.Show("The value could not be parsed as a date.")
End If
```

If you want to control how the parsing is attempted (such as the culture), you would want to use the overload that accepts the IFormatProvider parameter.